# Map method in React and native js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm having trouble understanding how the map method works in React.
In javascript, the map returns a new array and doesn't iterate,
Why in React it is loop the elements

Comment: "In javascript, the map returns a new array and doesn't iterate" this is false, the map method does return a new array but in doing so it definitely traverses the current array. "Why in React it is loop the elements" have no idea what this means, and I've been using React for the better part of a decade now. Please post some code that illustrates your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `map` method does iterate over an array in Javascript. It just also happens to return a new array, whose elements are built using a callback function passed in to `map` which acts on each element of the original array.

For example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log(arr.map(num => num + 1)) 


===> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It works exactly like `forEach`, but instead of simply iterating, it returns a new array.

You can also use `map` to just make a shallow copy of the array:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
let arrCopy = arr.map(num => num)

console.log(arrCopy)


===> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hence why it's easy to build out an array of elements using `map` in React:

```
let names = ["Mark", "Kelly", "Mike"]

return (
  <ol>
    {names.map(name => {
      return (
        <li>{name}</li>
      )})}
  </ol>
)
```

Comment: The `map` function is iterating over the names array, yes. The `map` function iterates over each element, passes each element to the anonymous function, and the anonymous function returns us the name with some `li` tags wrapped around that name. Then the entire `map` function returns us an array of all those created `li` elements.